# How pass data between component father to child in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm new in the typescript and iam tryng to pass data between to components, and i don't have any idea how to do this in typescript

my father component

```
const  Main: React.FC = () => {
  const [orgsData, setOrgsData] = useState<Array<Orgs>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadOrgs()
  },[])
  const loadOrgs = () =>{
    Services.getOrgs()
      .then(response =>{
        setOrgsData(response.data)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
  return (
    <Box flex = {1} >
        <Navbar/>
        <SubHeader/>
        <OrgsList data = {orgsData}/>
        <Footer/>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

my child component

```
import Orgs from '../api/interfaces'

interface OrgList {
  data: Orgs[]
}

export default function OrgList(props: OrgList) {
  const data = props;
  return (
    <Center>
      <Box>
        <Flex flexDirection="column">
          {data.map((item) => ( 

          <Box
            padding={3}
            w={350}
            h='auto'
            borderRadius={14}
            backgroundColor="#ffffff"
            shadow={1}
          >
            <Flex flexDirection='row'>
              <Box>
                <Image alt = '' borderRadius={6} w={50} h={50} source={ReactIcon} />
              </Box>
              <Flex flexDirection='column'>
                <Box marginLeft={2}>
                  <Heading
                    fontSize={16}
                    color="#2196f3"
                    fontWeight={500}
                  >
                    {item.login}
                  </Heading>
                  <Heading
                    fontSize={16}
                    color="#636363"
                    fontWeight={400}
                    overflow='hidden'
                  >
                    React website and its localizations
                  </Heading>
                </Box>
              </Flex>
            </Flex>
            <Flex flexDirection='row' justifyContent='flex-end'>
              <Button
                marginTop={3}
                padding={2}
                size='sm'
                borderRadius={16}
                backgroundColor='#91CBF9'
                startIcon={
                  <Icon
                    as={<SalvoAzul />}
                    size='sm'
                  >
                  </Icon>
                }
              >
                <Text
                  textAlign='center'
                  color='#2196f3'
                >
                  Salvar
                </Text>
              </Button>
            </Flex>
          </Box>
          ))}
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </Center>

  );
}
```

When i try to map my props return this error

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'OrgList'

I'm new in the typescript and i don't have any idea how to pass data between this components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below syntax would be easier to work with.

## Parent

Check the name of the prop you are passing down to the child. In your given code, you are passing **data**.

```
const  Main: React.FC = () => {

  ...

  return (
    <Box flex = {1} >
        <Navbar/>
        <SubHeader/>
        <OrgsList data = {orgsData}/> // <- Passing "data" as prop name.
        <Footer/>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

## Child

1. In **Props**, declare the prop name and type you want. We declare "data" here.
2. Then in **Child Component**, use the prop directly by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
import Orgs from '../api/interfaces'

interface Props {
  data: Orgs[] // <-- Prop name should be "data"
}

export const OrgList: React.FC<Props> = ({data}) => {
  // const data = props; <-- DELETE - data is extracted directly above

  // Tip: You can rename "data" by changing ({data}) to ({data: renamedData})
  //      above. Note that "renamedData" is NOT a Type!
  //      (Refer to "Assigning to new variables names and providing default values"
  //      in the given link for "destructuring".)


  return (
    <Center>
      ...
    </Center>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change child line from:

const data = props;

To instead say:

const data = props.data:

This is because you called it "data" when you passed it to the component in your line:

Had you instead said banana={orgsData} then child component would have referred to it as props.banana.